# Zend_Session::start overwites application.ini settings

Tags: zend-framework

If I use Zend_Session::start() in my bootstrap, it overwrites any resource.session settings I have made in my application.ini.  Is this expected behaviour?  Does that mean that all Zend resources should be configured either a) in the bootstrap, or b) in the application.ini, but not in both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly start the session, it will happen automatically on first use.

If you must start the session yourself, make sure you bootstrap the session resource first, eg

```
protected function _initSessionstart()
{
    $this->bootstrap('session');
    Zend_Session::start();
}
```

Another consideration... if you name your bootstrap method `_initSession()`, this will be run instead of the resource plugin of the same name. This is by design so you can write custom bootstrap overrides.